# How do I integrate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}7\sin(\sqrt{x})dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

So, quick backstory. My semester just started and we are starting off by learning integration by parts. Which hasn't caused me much trouble except for this problem. $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}7\sin(\sqrt{x})dx$$ I 'm going to post my steps that I have taken so far, but I stopped since I don't seem to be going anywhere. $$7\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}\sin(\sqrt{x})dx u=\sin(\sqrt{x})$$ 
 $u=\sin(\sqrt{x})$, $du=\frac{1}{2}\cos(\sqrt{x})*x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$, $dv=dx$,$v=x$
So applying $\int udv=uv-\int vdu$ I end with $$x\sin(\sqrt{x})-\int x\frac{1}{2}\cos(\sqrt{x})*x^{\frac{-1}{2}} \rightarrow x\sin(\sqrt{x})-\frac{1}{2}\int \cos(\sqrt{x})*x^{\frac{1}{2}} $$ (Left the constant 7 out until the end) Then I do the same to the remaining integral for 2 more times until i realized I'm not going anywhere. So a detailed procedure on how to solve this integral would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to first change variables $u = \sqrt{x}$ so that $I = \int_0^{\pi/2} 14 u \sin(u) du$. Now you can do integration by parts.

Comment: You should start with $u=\sqrt{x}$. Since $x=u^2$, $dx=2udu$, and then you have $2 \int u \sin(u) du$. If you were good at other problems, it should be clear how to proceed from there. The limits they gave you sort of suggest that this is what you should do, by the way.

Comment: From where you left off at $2\int u\sin(u)du$ I understand what to do after that, but I'm having trouble understanding how you got there... @Ian

Comment: @Kenshin He just did a $u$ substitution.  With the integral $\int \limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}} 7 \sin{(\sqrt{x})} \,dx$, if you let $u = \sqrt{x}$, then we can square both sides to get $u^{2} = x$.  Differentiating both sides gives $2udu = dx$.  So now we can substitute into the original problem $u$ in place of $\sqrt{x}$ and $2udu$ in place of $dx$.  That's why $\int \limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}} 7 \sin{(\sqrt{x})} \,dx =\int \limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (7)(2u) \sin{(u)} \,du $.

Comment: @Kenshin Notice that the limits of integration change when you do $u$-substitution.  The way to figure out the new limits is to look at the old limits.  So with the substitution $u = \sqrt{x}$, we have when $x = 0$, $u = \sqrt{0} = 0$, so the new lower limit is $0$.  When $x = \frac{\pi^{2}}{4}$, $u = \sqrt{\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}} = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so the new upper limit is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @Kenshin Also, Ian's answer is incomplete.  You don't get $2\int u \sin{u} \,du$, because we have the constant $7$ to deal with in the original problem.  So it actually becomes $\int (7)(2) u \sin{u} \,du = \int 14 u \sin{u} \,du$.

Comment: @user46944 That was perfect, I understand it completely now. I've never changed the limits of the integration so i didn't know how the change happened, so thanks for that. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi^2/4}7\sin(\sqrt{x})dx$$
Let $u=\sqrt x$, $x=u^2$, $dx=2udu$
$$I'=14\int u\sin(u)du=14\left(u\int \sin u du-\int \left(\frac d{du}u\right)\left(\int \sin u du\right)du\right)
\\=14(-u\cos u+\sin u)$$
$$I=14(-u\cos u+\sin u)_0^{\pi/2}=14$$

Comment: Great , thanks a lot!